# Broken Regex (or I am)?

Tags: ios, regex, xcode

I'm trying to Regex each method signature and 'open curly brace' in all files. What I have works in bbedit and others. Any idea as to why in Xcode i get only the first line and can't also get the curly brace? Xcode: Version 4.6.3 
Here's what I have tried:

```
(^-\s*\(.*?\).*?[\s\s]*?)\{
(^\+\s*\(.*?\).*?[\s\s]*?)\{
(^-\s*\(.*?\).*?[\s\s]*?)$\s*\{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode doesn't use multi-line regexes. I know; I tried.